# Using CSS Grid to arrange some HMTL elements in a Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I need help with some CSS code that will help me arrange some HTML elements on a web page in a certain way using CSS grids.
The way I need to arrange these elements is shown in the image included. As can be seen, I have a grid with two columns - the left column is taking about 2/3 of the width of the browser window and the right column is taking about 1/3rd of the width of the browser window. Into the right column, I have a text area which is occupying most of the available space leaving only a small space on the sides. The height of the text area should be such that it occupies the whole height of the browser window.
The left column is further divided into two columns of equal width and in each column there are 4 rows and there is a button element in each row of the two columns with a very small margin. All buttons are of the same height and width and four rows should occupy the full height of the browser window. Please note that I would like the external grid (with black lines) to occupy the whole width and height of the browser window, the blue rectangle represents the text area and the green rectangle represent button elements inside the cells of the grid.
Thank your help.
[image: image showing arrangement I need]

The code I have tried so far is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .outer-grid {
            display: grid;
            grid-gap: 1rem;
            grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
            height: fit-content;
            /* Set implicit rows */
          
          
        }

        .main {
            display: grid;
            height: auto;
            grid-gap: 1rem;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
           
        }

        .bodes {
            display: grid;
            height: auto;
            grid-template-rows: repeat(5, auto);
           
        }


        .textAreas {
            height: 100vh; 
            width: auto;
          
        
        }

        .btn {
            height: 30px ;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="outer-grid">
        <div >
            <div class="bodes">
                <button class="btn">A</button>
                <button class="btn">A</button>
                <button class="btn">A</button>
                <button class="btn">A</button>
                <button class="btn">A</button>
                <button class="btn">A</button>
                <button class="btn">A</button>
                <button class="btn">A</button>
            </div>

            
        </div>
        <div>
            <textarea class="textAreas" ></textarea>
        </div>
        

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where is your code, show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could place all elements as siblings inside the outer-container element. Then use grid-template-areas to place them in the DOM, using grid-area on each unique selector as reference to itself.

By using a ***fractional*** unit of measurement, you do not need to define the `width` and `height` of the ***childrens*** elements as they will take up that ***fractional*** amount of the **parents** *width/height*. So if you have ***4 rows***, *`1 fr`* on each `grid-template-rows`, will mean the children will take up ***25%*** of the parents height, which is `100vh` ***100*** => ***view height*** => ***100 / 4 = 25%***

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outer-cont {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas: "one two text-area" "three four text-area" "five six text-area" "seven eight text-area";
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.text-area {
  grid-area: text-area;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.btn {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;  
}

.one {
  grid-area: one;
}

.two {
  grid-area: two;
}

.three {
  grid-area: three;
}

.four {
  grid-area: four;
}

.five {
  grid-area: five;
}

.six {
  grid-area: six;
}

.seven {
  grid-area: seven;
}

.eight {
  grid-area: eight;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="outer-cont">
    <div class="text-area">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sed nibh ut eros viverra molestie. Praesent in neque nec elit aliquet mattis. Praesent dui sapien, placerat vitae dignissim a, dictum eu massa. Nam vel libero sodales, commodo dui ac, porttitor
      lacus. Duis tempus rhoncus lacus sit amet ornare. Phasellus pulvinar nibh et metus molestie tempus. Vestibulum ligula nibh, ultricies sed ex non, euismod blandit enim. Sed ac libero non justo maximus sodales sit amet quis augue. Maecenas sit amet
      sapien tellus. Vivamus ornare libero urna, sed gravida urna euismod eu. Vestibulum non varius est. Quisque sed arcu finibus, aliquet odio vitae, facilisis enim. Etiam malesuada maximus ante feugiat molestie. Sed elementum dignissim ex ac cursus.
    </div>
    <button class="one btn">
       A 
    </button>
    <button class="two btn">
       B 
    </button>
    <button class="three btn">
       C 
    </button>
    <button class="four btn">
       D
    </button>
    <button class="five btn">
       E
    </button>
    <button class="six btn">
       F
    </button>
    <button class="seven btn">
      G
    </button>
    <button class="eight btn">
    H
    </button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you comment and support. The solution you have kindly provided works and places the buttons and the text area in the way I want, however, the total button area and the text area height does not occupy the full height of the browser window. You may see what I mean if we run the code snippet and then click Full page.

Comment: @FaheemAhmad yes, I see I had a typo in the code => `100hv` should have been `100vh` I have corrected the typo and it works as intended. Glad to see you found an answer to your issue however. If you feel the answer added value to your question you can up vote it if you'd like and as always happy coding =)

Comment: Thank you very much Dale. Yes, your solution is indeed working perfectly now. It does add to my understanding and learning. Thank you very much for your support. Greatly appreciated!